# Invalid preceding regular expression given by find

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for uncompressed log files in the directory to compress. When I run the command, I get an error: find: Invalid preceding regular expression

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '*.log.[0-9]\{1,3\}$' -exec gzip -9 {} \;
```

Comment: `-regex '*.log.` what does that `*` match? zero or more of ... ?

Comment: it is "api.log.2021-06-20"

Answer (score 0):

The `*.log.[0-9]\{1,3\}$` is an invalid regex - the `*` does not follow any group. You can prepend it with `.` to match any character. I *guess* you want:

```
.*\.log\.[0-9]\{1,3\}$
```

You can learn regex fast and with fun with regex crosswords online.